# UIPasteboard - cannot copy text

Tags: objective-c, iphone, nsstring, uipasteboard

This code should copy the string to the generalPasteboard, as the [[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] string] object, but the method causes the program to terminate.

```
- (void)copyResultToPasteboard {
    NSString *message = self.resultTextView.text;
    [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].string = message;
    [message release];
}
```

I think it's something to do with format, seeing as the method works if the message is set to a literal string, but resultTextView.text is just an NSString... I don't fully understand, can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that `resultTextView.text` is returning a copy of the backing store, and not the actual `NSString*` used to store the data? Looking over the Apple documentation, it seems likely it's just returning the internal pointer (unretained). Calling release on a string being used by the `UITextView` class could cause this behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

You're sending `-release` to an object which you didn't (or at least, which it doesn't appear you have, from the snippit) first `-retain`, `+alloc` or get through `-copy`ing another object.